# Show all search help in maintenance view-abap

Tags: sap-data-dictionary

I made a maintenance view to a table that contains 2 foreign keys, when I use the search help only shows the parameter of the foreign key:

[image]

but what I want is to show all parameters of the search help like this:

[image]

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance,

Kind regards.

P.S: I am sorry if I had misspelling or any grammar errors, english isn't my native language and I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem here is in the definition of the search help. It may be missing those columns in SE11 → Search help → **Parameter** table.

Or, you may just re-use the search help from the table you've sent as an example (i.e. INVENTARIO). Then, you would change the current search help in the definition of underlaying transparent table that you use in your maintenance view (SE11 → Database table → tab Entry help/check → column **Srch Help**) to the search help used in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You should mark the parameters with positions, otherwise they won't be showed during output.

Also your selection method view should include all these fields:

[image]

[image]